# Query Date From a Table in Access VBA

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I've looked around everywhere but I've found any solutions. I'm trying to query a date from a table in Access VBA but after trying various placements of "#", I still can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
Dim varStartDate As Date

varStartDate = "SELECT Employees.StartDate FROM Employees WHERE Employees.Name LIKE Manny"
```

I get type mismatch error.

I also tried

```
varStartDate = "# " & "SELECT Employees.StartDate FROM Employees WHERE Employees.Name LIKE Manny" & " #"
```

Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type mismatch error was because you were attempting to assign a string to `varStartDate`, but since it was declared `As Date`, it can't accept *"SELECT Employees.StartDate FROM ..."*.

I think you can get what you need with `DLookup`.

```vb
Dim varStartDate As Variant
varStartDate = DLookup("StartDate", "Employees", "[Name]='Manny'")
```

If another issue is that `Employees.StartDate` is text instead of Date/Time datatype, maybe you also need to convert the value you get from `DLookup`.

```vb
If Not IsNull(varStartDate) Then
    varStartDate = CDate(varStartDate)
End If
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much for a quick reply.